# Всегда вначале ввода числа

Tags: java, массивы

Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры натуральное число большее 3, которое сохраняется в переменную n.

Если пользователь ввёл не подходящее число, то программа должна просить пользователя повторить ввод.

Создать массив из n случайных целых чисел из отрезка [0;n] и вывести его на экран.
Создать второй массив только из чётных элементов первого массива, если они там есть, и вывести его на экран.

```
public class Zadachi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int n = 0;
        int a = 0;
        int count = 0;
        do {
            Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введите число больше 3");
            if (src.hasNextInt()) {
                n = src.nextInt();
            }
            else System.out.println("Повторите ввод числа");
        }
        while (n > 4);
        int[] Mas1 = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < Mas1.length; i++) {
            Mas1[n] = a + (int) (Math.random() * n);
            System.out.print(Mas1 + " ");
            if (Mas1[i] != 0 & Mas1[i] % 2 ==0) count++;
        }

       // System.out.println("");
        if (count > 0) {
            int[] Mas2 = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0, b = 0; i < Mas1.length; i++) {
                if (Mas1[i] % 2 == 0 & Mas1[i] != 0) {
                    Mas2[b] = Mas1[i];
                    System.out.print(Mas2[b] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Всегда при вводе числа больше трех исполняется только блок else и не переходит к выполнению других функций

Comment: всегда в начале при вводе числа больше трех исполняется только else и не переходит к выполнению других функций

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, блок else не выполняется при вводе числа больше 3

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий вариант. Изменения заметите сами:

```
    int n = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число больше 3");

        if(src.hasNextInt()) {
            n = src.nextInt();
            if(n < 4) {
                System.out.println("Число должно быть больше 3!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Повторите ввод числа");
        }

    } while (n < 4);

    int[] Mas1 = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < Mas1.length; i++) {
        Mas1[i] = a + (int) (Math.random() * n);
        System.out.print(Mas1[i] + " ");
        if (Mas1[i] % 2 == 0 && Mas1[i] != 0) count++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    int[] Mas2 = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0, b = 0; i < Mas1.length; i++) {
        if (Mas1[i] % 2 == 0 && Mas1[i] != 0) {
            Mas2[b] = Mas1[i];
            System.out.print(Mas2[b] + " ");
            b++;
        }
    }
```

А почему вы не можете выйти из цикла, когда вы пишите число больше 3? А потому, что цикл будет выполняться "while n > 4", то есть пока n больше 4. Вот он и повторяется.